# ANT checkout task fails

Tags: java, svn, ant, build, task

I've got the following markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="SampleBuild" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <property name="SvnAntDir" value="C:/Program Files/Apache/svnant-1.2.1/doc" />  
    <property name="src" value="_src_" />
    <property name="build" value="_build_"/>
    <property name="dist" value="${build}/_jars_" />    

    <path id= "svnant.classpath" >
        <fileset dir= "${SvnAntDir}" >
            <include name= "*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="pre-cleanup">
        <delete dir="${src}" />     
        <delete file="${dist}/Project.jar" />
        <delete includeEmptyDirs="true" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${build}/_classes_/sevgok/" />
        </delete>

        <mkdir dir="${src}" />
        <tstamp />
    </target>

    <target name="checkout" depends="pre-cleanup">      
        <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />       
        <svn>
            <checkout url="svn://p-subversion/Project/trunk" revision="HEAD" destPath="${src}" />
        </svn>
    </target>   

    <target name="compile" depends="checkout">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}/_classes_" debug="on" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="${classpath}" />
                <fileset dir="./_libs_">
                    <include name="*.jar" />
                    <include name="*.zip" />
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>   
</project>
```

Problem occurs when trying to make a build. The error message is next:

```
checkout: [svn] <Checkout> started ...
[svn] svn: svn://p-subversion/Project/trunk` doesn't exist
[svn] svn: svn://p-subversion/Project/trunk` doesn't exist
[svn] <Checkout> failed!

Build FAILED
C:\build.minimal.xml: (line of code which points to <svn> openning tag): Can't checkout.`
```

Simultaneously it is possible to make a checkout with Tortoise SVN client using the url.

Help!

**EDIT**

I tried using -v key when building and got the following:

`Caused by: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException: org.tigris
.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: URL 'svn://p-subversion/Project/trunk
' doesn't exist`

**EDIT**

Is there any alternative to SvnAnt? It would be great if it was also well documentated.

Thanks

**EDIT**

So code that works for me is:

```
<target name="checkout" depends="pre-cleanup">
    <exec dir="${basedir}" executable="svn" failonerror="true">
        <arg line="checkout -r ${revision} ${SvnUrl} ${src}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

where `${SvnUrl}` is the same URL I used before.

Comment: So, does svn://p-subversion/Project/trunk exist? What happens if you execute the checkout command yourself?

Comment: Yes, it does. An ordinary checkout of a head revision to a folder I chose happens.

Comment: could it be that Project is spelled with a lower p in the repository or something alike?

Comment: @oers no, it is spelled right.

Comment: could you run with ant -v? This will show more debug information, maybe it will help.

Comment: It seems to be something local. Do you use/need a proxy? Is ant executed on the same machine as your tortoise test? Does tortoise use the same protocol svn:// or http://? Nothing more i can think of :(

Comment: Ant and Tortoise client use the same `svn` protocol. Ant is executed on the same machine as my tortoise test. As far as I understand I don't use proxy.

Comment: Your edited in -v output suggests there is a trailing character (space?) on the URL that is making it fail.  Is that just a facet of how your copied and pasted?

Comment: @martinclayton Going backwards I can copy url from my *.xml file then paste it to Tortoise SVN client and make a successful checkout. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `svnant` does not work at all you could just execute svn from the command line:

```
<exec executable="svn" dir="DIRECTORY_WHERE_COMMAND_EXECUTES">
  <arg line="checkout svn://p-subversion/Project/trunk $src"/>
</exec>
```

You would have to install a [svn command line client](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html). Make sure, that you add the `bin`-Directory of the client to the `PATH`.
But take care to install the same client version as your tortoise client. If they mismatch they will make the working copy unaccessible for the other.

Comment: As I understand `dir` attribute shouldn't point to `DIRECTORY_OF_SVN_CLIENT`. In my case, for example, it points to folder in which my build files are stored and from where I execute them (`${basedir}`). But anyway thanks! That helped.

Answer (score 0):

What is `p-subversion` supposed to be? SVN URLs, just like HTTP URLs, begin with a hostname. If `p-subversion` isn't a hostname that will point to your computer, then the checkout will fail. Perhaps it should look more like this?

`svn://localhost/p-subversion/Project/trunk`

[edit]If it's a Windows share...

`file://p-subversion/Project/trunk`

the `svn://` URL assumes a hostname, but in the case of a share some other part of the OS is already negotiating the TCP connection. Refer to it like you would any other folder.

Comment: I have a network share and make checkouts from remote machine (using `//p-subversion/[RepositoryName]/[trunk|branch]`-like urls) regularly.

Comment: I've edited my answer to account for handling a Windows share.