# SVN Operations from ANT Build Tool Not Working for "svn://" protocol

Tags: svn, ant, build-tools

My build.xml code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Sample build file used to retrieve svnant's sources -->
<project name="svn-test" basedir="." default="checkoutLatest">>       
  <!--  all properties are in build.properties --> 
  <property file="build.properties" /> 
  <!-- path to the svnant libraries. Usually they will be located in ANT_HOME/lib -->
  <path id="svnant.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>  
  <!-- load the svn task -->
  <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="svnant.classpath" />
  <target name="checkoutLatest">
    <mkdir dir="src_latest"/>
    <svn username="name" password="passwd">
     <status path="svn://sc........../"/>   
     <checkout url="svn://s.../" revision="HEAD" destPath="src_latest"/>  
    </svn>
  </target>   </project>
```

I can do the SVN Operations with **https://** protocol, but it shows error with **svn://** protocol. Below is the error

```
> Buildfile: C:\build.xml checkoutLatest:
>       [svn] <Checkout> started ...
>       [svn] svn: Unknown host url path
>       [svn] svn: Unknown host url path
>       [svn] url path
>       [svn] <Checkout> failed !
> 
> BUILD FAILED C:\build.xml:21: Can't checkout
> 
> Total time: 3 seconds
```

Comment: Check similar topic under following site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573681/ant-checkout-task-fails

Comment: Hi Chris.. Thanks for your Suggestion... I found the solution by Updating SVNant jars..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously I used SVNAnt 1.2 Jars which had an Issue with svn:// protocol. So I downloaded **svnant-1.3.1** Jars from [http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html][1]

Checkout Code:

```html
 <target name="checkoutThis">
   <mkdir dir="src_1"/>
   
    <svnSetting svnkit="true" username="er351a" password="welcome2ibm" id="svn.settings"/>
   
    <svn javahl="${javahl}">
     <checkout url="svn://scm.it.att.com:14373/BGW_MIGR/trunk/BGWCommonEJB3" revision="HEAD" destPath="src_1" />         
    </svn>
```